# df.plot fails after pandas upgrade to v 1.0.1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, upgrade

I was using pandas 0.23.4 and just upgraded to 1.0.1.

I have a code which generated a dataframe and I would plot it as a stacked bar plot `df.plot(kind='bar')` and as an area plot `df.plot.area()`. It was working fine. I decided to upgrade pandas and now neither of the plot commands work. Here is an example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df["col1"]=[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.0]
df["col2"]=[0.1,0.5,0.2,0.2]
df['col3']=[0.1,0.0,0.1,0.8]
df.plot.area()
```

This gives the error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_NoValueType'`.

I don't know how to fix this. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

EDIT: Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-96-b436d7233c8a>", line 1, in <module>
    df.plot.area()

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1363, in area
return self(kind="area", x=x, y=y, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 847, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py", line 61, in plot
plot_obj.generate()

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 262, in generate
self._setup_subplots()

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 321, in _setup_subplots
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1257, in add_subplot
 a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 74, in __init__
self.update_params()

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 136, in update_params
return_all=True)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 467, in get_position
fig_bottom = fig_bottoms[rows].min()

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 32, in _amin
return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_NoValueType'
```

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message.

Comment: works on my machine with pandas 1.0.1

Comment: Added the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I rebooted my the computer and now everything works. No idea what was wrong before!